# Ubuntu 14 installation won't recognize one of my hard drives

Tags: partitioning, 14.04, hard-drive, system-installation

So basically I used to have a working machine with ubuntu and windows 7 on a single hard drive.

Suddenly, my machine fried, so I got a new rig. 
Now, I installed windows 7 on a new sdd drive, and I want to re install ubuntu on my old drive. I reformatted the old drive and now for some reason, the ubuntu installation isn't recognizing it, even though the drive appears fine on windows 7. I'm attaching some "screen(phone) shots" so you can see, notice how the 3rd drive (drive G) in windows 7 isn't appearing in the installation.

Any thoughts ?

[Windows 7 screen](https://imgur.com/BwGmVVV)
, 
[Ubuntu 14 installation screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJLk1.jpg)
*sorry for the bad quality, I took them with my phone out of laziness*

Comment: In the Ubuntu install screen, that is just a list of available partitions on a drive.  Try clicking the drop-down menu just below *Device for boot loader installation*.  You should be able to select any of your available drives and create a new partition table if needed.

Comment: I already did that, drive didn't appear there either.

Answer (score 0):

Enter your system BIOS, make sure that you do not have RAID options enabled and set your SATA controller to AHCI and not IDE. (This was my difficulty)

Comment: If this doesn't work, please add your 'fdisk -l' and '/etc/fstab' output in an edit to your question (using livedvd).